# Convert Html Pages to Jsp Pages

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp

How can I convert My Html pages like Login, Register etc to Jsp pages to make them Interactive? 
Can this be done in EclipsejEE or My Eclipse?

Comment: ... On its own this question doesn't make much sense. A valid HTML page *is* a valid JSP page. JSPs are just templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just you need to rename your html file to .jsp file, it will be converted...example: from login.html to login.jsp..

hope it helps you ...
thank you..